# Refresh a table in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, razor

I have a form on my page like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddRecipeLine", "Kitchen", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "addRecipeLine" }))
        {
            <div class="medium-4 columns">
                @Html.DropDownList("ingredients", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ingredients, "--Select Ingredients--")
            </div>
            <div class="medium-4 columns">
                @Html.TextBox("quantity", null, new { placeholder = "Quantity", @type = "number", min = "1" })
                @Html.TextBox("recipeId", null, new { @type = "hidden", @value = @ViewBag.recipe.Id })
            </div>
            <div class="medium-4 columns">
                <button class="button tiny">Add</button>
            </div>
        }
```

I use Jquery like this to submit this form

```
$('#addRecipeLine').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var ingredientId = $('#ingredients').val();
    var quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val());
    var rId = $('#recipeId').val();

    if (ingredientId != '' && quantity != '') {
        InstaFood.RecipeLine.Add(ingredientId, quantity, rId, function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            $('#addRecipeLine')[0].reset();
        });
    }
});
```

In the same view I have a table which shows the data added through this form.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Ingredient Name (KCals)</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (var recipeLine in RecipeLine.GetByRecipe(@ViewBag.recipe.Id))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@recipeLine.GetIngredient().Name (@recipeLine.GetIngredient().KiloCalories)</td>
            <td> @recipeLine.Quantity</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

What I want is that this table record gets refreshed whenever I add data through the form. Like some ajax thing which will refresh this table when ever user submits the form.

Comment: you have two options from what I understand. 1. to add the new record manually as a td or 2. do an ajax get method and get all records from db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use callback in JQuery submit. Append to table where you are doing  below thing

```
console.log(result);
```